# Page adds #link to a elements error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, https

I have a basic html page with the following a element:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

and other a elements written the same way. Everytime I click on one of them, it results in the current url turning into:

```
localhost:8080/firstApp/index.html#https://www.google.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have `#` before url in href attribute.

Comment: try to run it in incognito window then let me know.

Comment: View the page source (ctrl+u), is the link rendered like that?  Also what server side language are you using and how are you running it locally?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: I have Java code in backend. @PawanSinghChauhan but it works fine on all pages except this one.

Comment: Sounds like something is changing the links client side on that page - check your plugins for that page - the ones that are not used on the other pages (if it is specific to that one page)

Comment: @sjahan it works fine in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine and redirecting to google page.
@Chayma Atallah